# How to print odd numbered fields from a text file using awk in Unix?

Tags: awk

I am unable to understand the answer given to it though certainly that helps to fulfil my requirement.

```
awk -F\| '{s="";for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) {s=s?s FS $i:$i} print s}' file
```

What does this `{s=s?s FS $i:$i} print s}` do? How does it print the required output? 
I know it is a ternary operator in use. But how does it evaluate the expression and print the output?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26858714/7552

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of it as a if-then-else

```
 {s=s?s FS $i:$i}
```

evaluate to

```
 { if ( s != "" ) s=s FS $i ; ## i=3,5,7,...
   else s=$i ; } ## i=1
```

this looks like a obscure code.

```
awk -F\| '{s="";for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) {s=s?s FS $i:$i} print s}' file
```

is equivalent to (easiest to understand)

```
awk -F\| '{s=$1;for (i=3;i<=NF;i+=2) {s=s FS $i} print s}' file
```

Comment: Superb explanation man !!!